# Dependent Validation Rule?

Tags: validation, validation-rule

How can I create a `Validation Rule` that makes a field required if some other fields are not null?

For example, if I were to enter a `Skillname`, then `Skill Type`, `Proficiency` and `Years of Experience` should become required.

Comment: if any of the below answers helped resolve your question, please mark it as Answered @lone . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Skillname__c)),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(SkillType__c),
        ISBLANK(Proficiency__c),
        ISBLANK(Experience__c)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have taken the example as : For Opportunity object , when Account id provided as an input then Description and Competitor information are mandator:

At validation rule "Error Condition Formula" will be as below :

```
IF(AccountId != null, 
  ( IF( OR(Description == null, MainCompetitors__c == null) , true, false) ),
   false
)
```

This will work.

PS: Please replace your field with the above rule fields.

Comment: You can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.